# Lucene: generateWordParts vs splitOnCaseChange

Tags: java, solr, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I am investigating `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`

I am confusing about `generateWordParts` and `splitOnCaseChange` parameters.

from java doc:
**generateWordParts**:

```
/**
   * Causes parts of words to be generated:
   * <p>
   * "PowerShot" =&gt; "Power" "Shot"
   */
  public static final int GENERATE_WORD_PARTS = 1;
```

**splitOnCaseChange:**

```
 /**
   * If not set, causes case changes to be ignored (subwords will only be generated
   * given SUBWORD_DELIM tokens)
   */
  public static final int SPLIT_ON_CASE_CHANGE = 64;
```

Can you show example which clarify the difference?

### P.S.

Also I don't understanf menaning of **SUBWORD_DELIM**

Comment: @Downvoters, do you really think that java doc is clear?

Comment: There is more documentation than just the documentation of the constants in the java file, though. From the documentation: generateWordParts: (integer, default 1) If non-zero, splits words at delimiters. For example:"CamelCase", "hot-spot" -> "Camel", "Case", "hot", "spot"

Answer (score 0):

First: The WordDelimiterFilter has been superseded by the Word Delimiter Graph Filter (which plays nice with phrase queries).

generateWordParts considers more than just case differences. I.e. `foo-bar` is split into `foo` and `bar`. Split on case change wouldn't do anything here, leaving a single `foo-bar` token.

The SUBWORD_DELIM references the `types` parameter, where you can include a file that defines which characters that can be assumed to split a token into subwords:

```
types
(optional) The pathname of a file that contains character => type mappings, which enable customization of this filter’s splitting behavior. Recognized character types: LOWER, UPPER, ALPHA, DIGIT, ALPHANUM, and SUBWORD_DELIM.
```

I assume you could use a SUBWORD_DELIM character as '|' or '.', where you'd split a word into two tokens if it contained either of those characters.

Comment: Can you provide class name for Word Delimiter Graph Filter ? I could not find it

Comment: It's [WordDelimiterGraphFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterGraphFilter.html) and Solr's factory is named the usual way, `solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory`.

Comment: Looks like WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory is not available in hibernate-search

Comment: It behaves mostly the same as the WordDelimiterFilter, but has better / actual support for phrase queries. [It was introduced as part of Solr 6.5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7619).